# How to activate Google My Business v4.9 API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-reviews

I am currently working on the development on a website for a client, and they want to display their Google Reviews in the footer. I am using PHP client libraries to so, and I've created OAuth2.0 credentials to access the API.

From the Google APIs documentation I see that I need to use the "Google My Business v4.9" API to do so, in order to use the accounts.locations.reviews. See the following screenshot to know the one I want to use :

[image: All apis]

The problem is when I want to activate this API on my Google Cloud projet, I can find all the Google My Business API, but not the "v4.9" (I've tryied searching for "my business", "google my business", "v4.9", etc... but I still can't find it. Here is what I get :

[image: APi search results]

I've tried accessing the service without activating any API, thinking that maybe the v4.9 API was maybe activated by default, but I get 403 error saying "SERVICE NOT ENABLED".

Has anyone encountered this problem, and do you know which API to call ? any piece of information would be really appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little bit more in the API documentation, I've found out that in order to have access to Google My Business API, you need to submit a form about your business so that Google authenthificates it.

Otherwise, the API will not be visible in the APIs library for your project.

See : https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#enable-the-api

The link to the form : https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfC_FKSWzbSae_5rOpgwFeIUzXUF1JCQnlsZM_gC1I2UHjA3w/viewform

Comment: Also note that v4.9 is mostly deprecated (except for the reviews + a few others).